# RabbitMQ crashing recently without reason

Tags: crash, warnings, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

We have a RabbitMQ node running on 4GB of RAM on a 20GB disk, shared with Redis (which does virtually nothing), usually coping with a few hundred messages a second.

However it has recently started crashing randomly, dumping no errors, not making any other warnings (e.g. Nagios), which is very odd behaviour.

Can anyone help us debug this problem?

Here's the status:

```
Status of node rabbit@cachingsessions ...
[{pid,13284},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","0.0.0"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","0.0.0"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","0.0.0"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.7.1"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
      {rabbitmq_mochiweb,"RabbitMQ Mochiweb Embedding","0.0.0"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.7.0-rmq0.0.0-hg"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","1.3-rmq0.0.0-git"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.7.1"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
     {os,{unix,linux}},
     {erlang_version,
         "Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-    threads:30]      [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
     {memory,
     [{total,201354672},
     {processes,104481264},
     {processes_used,104294840},
     {system,96873408},
     {atom,1348809},
     {atom_used,1326854},
     {binary,41880856},
     {code,14331631},
     {ets,29589448}]},
     {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.39999999961815885},
 {vm_memory_limit,838044876}]
...done.
```

Sadly that's all the info I have to go on due to no error logs at all.

Cheers